# dropdown selection should be filled from array

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu, multidimensional-array

I have the following functions which output the data in array.

```
$newOpt  = $ent->getAll($code); 
// This code generates the following array
    Array ( 
        [NC] => Array (
            [101] => banana,
            [102] => orange,
            [103] => apple,
        )

        [LN] => Array (
            [106] => brean,
            [110] => pen,
            [132] => book,
        )
    )


    $newOptReg  = $ent->getSelected($code); 
    // This code generates the following array
    Array (

        [NC] => Array (
            [101] => banana, 
        )

        [LN] => Array (
            [110] => pen,
            [132] => book,
        )
    )
```

What I want is if the `$newOptReg` value is found in `$newOpt` array, then fill the dropdown by the value `$newOpt`, but make the drop down selected the appropriate element in `$newOptReg`. The code I have at the moment:

```
 <form  id="check" name="ch" method="post" action="">

                <table class="table zebra-striped table-bordered table-striped span7">
                    <tbody>

                    // NC always select only one
                        <?php if ($newOpt['NC'] == '') { } else {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="5%">
                                    <h5>NC</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td class="span6">

                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="input" name="offi[]">   
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <? foreach ($newOpt as $orgKey => $list) {
                                            foreach ($list as $key=>$val) {
                                                $selected = isset($newOptReg[$orgKey][$key]) ? 'selected="selected" ' : '';
                                            ?>
                                            <option <?=$selected?> value='<?=$key?>,NC'

                                                ><?=$val?></option>

                                            <? }
                                        } ?>

                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>


                            // But LN has more element which could be selected
                        <?php if ($newOptC['LN'] == '') { } else {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="250px">
                                    <h5>LN</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td width="10%">

                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="input" name="offi[]">   
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <? 
                                           foreach ($newOptC as $orgKey => $list) {
                                            foreach ($list as $key=>$val) { 
                                                $selected = isset($newOptReg[$orgKey][$key]) ? 'selected="selected" ' : '';
                                                $va = isset($newOptReg[$orgKey][$key]) ? $key : '';
                                                $valt = current($list);  

                                            ?>
                                            <option <?=$selected?> value='<?=$key?>,LN'

                                                ><?=$val?></option>
                                            <?php unset($valt); ?>

                                            <? }
                                        } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <?php if ($newOptC['Coach'] == '') { } else {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="150px">
                                    <h5>LN</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                    <select class="input-xlarge" id="input" name="offi[]">   
                                        <option value=""><?=_('[select]')?></option>
                                        <? foreach ($newOptC as $orgKey => $list) {
                                            foreach ($list as $key=>$val) {
                                            ?>
                                            <option value='<?=$key?>,LN'
                                                <? if (isset($newOptReg[$orgKey][$key])) {  ?>
                                                    selected="selected"
                                                    <?  } ?>
                                                ><?=$val?></option>

                                            <? }
                                        } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                            <?php } ?>    
</form>
```

What the above code generates is, three drop-down Form filled with proper result, Except the second LN and third LN shows the same array element is being selected ("book"), But what i need is in first LN selected 110- Pen element and the next will be 132-book. How can i achieve that? I really Appreciate any help!

Comment: The code seems incomplete and is certainly hard to understand with all that embedded php ( not such a good practice ). Please provide a MWE ( Minimal Working Example ) for best results: what you want to achieve, what's the input.